# How can I successfully deploy firebase functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'm trying to deploy my Firebase functions using the Firebase CLI (firebase deploy --only functions), but I keep getting the following error:

```
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app-compat@0.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app@0.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: idb@7.0.1 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-02-18T13_26_52_861Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app-compat@0.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app@0.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: idb@7.0.1 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-02-18T13_27_30_745Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app-compat@0.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app@0.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: idb@7.0.1 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-02-18T13_27_26_236Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772
Build failed: npm ERR! code EUSAGE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app-compat@0.2.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/app@0.9.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/component@0.6.3 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/logger@0.4.0 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: @firebase/util@1.9.2 from lock file
npm ERR! Missing: idb@7.0.1 from lock file
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Clean install a project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Usage:
npm ERR! npm ci
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Options:
npm ERR! [-S|--save|--no-save|--save-prod|--save-dev|--save-optional|--save-peer|--save-bundle]
npm ERR! [-E|--save-exact] [-g|--global] [--global-style] [--legacy-bundling]
npm ERR! [--omit <dev|optional|peer> [--omit <dev|optional|peer> ...]]
npm ERR! [--strict-peer-deps] [--no-package-lock] [--foreground-scripts]
npm ERR! [--ignore-scripts] [--no-audit] [--no-bin-links] [--no-fund] [--dry-run]
npm ERR! [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> [-w|--workspace <workspace-name> ...]]
npm ERR! [-ws|--workspaces] [--include-workspace-root] [--install-links]
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! aliases: clean-install, ic, install-clean, isntall-clean
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Run "npm help ci" for more info

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /www-data-home/.npm/_logs/2023-02-18T13_27_31_642Z-debug-0.log; Error ID: beaf8772

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        randomNumberCall(europe-west3)
        randomNumberRequest(europe-west3)
        stripeCheckout(europe-west3)
        stripeCheckoutWithoutDbQueries(europe-west3)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
Error: There was an error deploying functions:
- Error Failed to create function stripeCheckout in region europe-west3
- Error Failed to create function stripeCheckoutWithoutDbQueries in region europe-west3
- Error Failed to create function randomNumberCall in region europe-west3
- Error Failed to create function randomNumberRequest in region europe-west3
```

Everything works fine when I test the functions with firebase emulators.

Here's the relevant part of my **`index.js`** file:

```
const stripe = require("stripe")(
    "sk_test_XXXXXXXX"
);

const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.stripeCheckout = functions
    .region("europe-west3")
    .https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
        console.log(data);

        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ["card"],
            line_items: data.items.map((item) => ({
                quantity: 1,
                price_data: {
                    currency: "eur",
                    unit_amount: item.price * 100,
                    product_data: {
                        name: item.summary,
                        // description: "description!"
                        images: [item.image]
                    }
                }
            })),

            mode: "payment",
            success_url: "http://localhost:4205/home?action=success",
            cancel_url: "http://localhost:4205/home?action=cancel"
        });

        return session.id;
    });
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this error? I appreciate your help!

I tried running npm install and npm ci to make sure all dependencies are installed, but it did not work.

I also watched this video and did everything the same way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r0tlQABfm9k&t=1064s&ab_channel=D-I-Ry

Comment: The error seems to indicate the problem is not in your code but the package.json. Can you check if your package.json is really in sync with package-lock.json? Does running `npm ci` locally give you the same error?

Comment: @yqlim no, running npm ci works just fine